# I was doing a time-pass problem that was created by myself, but somehow I am stuck with the output

Tags: javascript

My program:

```js
const data = [
  {
    marvel: {
      name: 'Thor',
      film: 'Thor',
      nickName: 'god of thunder',
    },
    dc: {
      name: 'Joker',
      film: ['Batman', 'Joker'],
    },
  },
  'Iron-Man',
  'Super-man',
];

let film = [];

const myFav = data.map(item => {
  if (typeof item === 'object') {
    let jokerDcfilms = [];
    let favCharacterFilms = [];
    let thorMarvelFilm = item.marvel.film;
    jokerDcfilms.push(item.dc.film);
    const dcFilms = jokerDcfilms.flat(1);
    favCharacterFilms = [...dcFilms, thorMarvelFilm];
  } else if (typeof item === 'string') {
    let favFilms = [];
    favFilms = [item];
  }
});
film = [...favCharacterFilms, ...favFilms];
console.log(film);
```

Expected output is:

```
[ 'Batman', 'Joker', 'Thor', 'Iron-man', 'Super-man' ]
```

Current output is:

```
[ 'Batman', 'Joker', 'Thor', 'super-man' ]
```

Why am I not getting expected output? I just want to insert all films in the data to a array and should print that array.

Note: Changing/altering data is not an option.

Comment: I turned your code into a runnable snippet. It produces an error, not the output you claim.

Comment: Anyway, you only assign `favFilms` an array with a single item, so it could never become an array with 2 or more items.

Answer (score 0):

You have to push in the array favFilms like this and it works as you want.

```
else if (typeof item === 'string') {
    favFilms.push(item);
}
```

Also initiliaze these arrays outside of the map function

```
let film = [];
let favFilms = [];
```

Answer (score 0):

You've defined `favFilms` as a blockscoped variable, so it is not accessible outside that block. Even if you would have defined it with a larger scope, you still reset it to have just one item, by assigning  `favFilms = [item]`. So whatever was already collected in an array, is now lost.

You should not use `.map` if you don't intend to use the array it returns. However, in this case it would actually be a good idea to capture the array it returns.

Flatten the array that you get returned:

```js
const data = [{marvel: {name: 'Thor',film: 'Thor',nickName: 'god of thunder',},dc: {name: 'Joker',film: ['Batman', 'Joker'],},},'Iron-Man','Super-man',];

const film = data.flatMap(item =>
    item.marvel ? item.dc.film.concat(item.marvel.film) : item
);
console.log(film);
```

Comment: That you my friend,